# How to return a matrix containing all zeros in Haskell

Tags: haskell

I am trying to work on this zero function. I know i can use this to print out desired number of zeros (Prelude> take 5 (repeat 0) ). 
Any help would be appreciated.

zero :: Int -> Int -> [[Double]]
Given positive integers representing the rows and columns, return a matrix
of those dimensions containing all zeros.

Comment: Two applications of [replicate](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:replicate) would be the easiest way I think.

Comment: `zero r c = take r (repeat (take c (repeat 0)))`

Answer (score 4):

### Replicate

Replicate is a prelude function with type `replicate :: Int -> a -> [a]`. It takes an integer and replicates something that amount of times. For your matrix, this will do the trick

```
zero row col = replicate row . replicate col $ 0
```

Comment: for your consideration https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions

Comment: Thanks, I thought it is such a basic question that there would be almost no difference between working code and a hint, but I'll keep that in mind for the next times

Comment: No worries. You bring a welcome enthusiasm, and it's appreciated. But consider if giving answers really help. Keep in mind, when someone is given the answer, without understanding, they'll lose in the end.